# Spring - How to use @RequestParam parameter of a Controller in a Custom Validator class?

Tags: spring, hibernate, validation, spring-mvc, customvalidator

I've got a problem about validation in Spring MVC with Hibernate.

I want a validator that valid user input, but the validation must be done out of the controller, so, in a separate validation class.

The situation: this is the head of my controller in which I want to do the validation. I need that id to retrieve a list of Booking of a specific car.

```
@PostMapping(value = "/rent")
    public ModelAndView vehicleRent(@ModelAttribute("newBooking") Booking booking, BindingResult bindingResult, @RequestParam("id") long id) {
```

But if i want to separate the logic out of this controller creating a custom validator, i have this result:

```
 public class BookingValidator implements Validator {

        @Autowired
        VehicleBO vehicleBo;

        @Override
        public boolean supports(Class<?> type) {
            return Booking.class.isAssignableFrom(type);
        }

        @Override
        public void validate(Object o, Errors errors) {

            Booking booking = (Booking) o;

        //other code

     rejectIfBookingExists(booking, 0, errors, "validation.booking.startdate.exists");
                }
            }

       public boolean rejectIfBookingExists(Booking booking, long id, Errors errors, String key){
        boolean exists = false;

         List<Booking> vehicleBookings = vehicleBo.getVehicleBookings(id);
        if (booking != null || booking.getStartDate() != null || booking.getFinishDate() != null) {
            for (Booking b : vehicleBookings) {
                if (booking.getStartDate().before((b.getFinishDate())) || booking.getStartDate().equals(b.getFinishDate())) {
                    errors.rejectValue("startDate", key);
                    exists = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return exists;
    }
}
```

In this way I cannot retrieve the list because i don't have the required id, could you explain me how to do that? Or,there are other ways to solve this problem?

Thanks!

EDIT:

This is the Booking class, as you can see it has a Vehicle object mapped inside

```
@Entity
public class Booking implements Serializable {

    @Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;


@ManyToOne
@JoinTable(name="user_booking", joinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="booking_id", referencedColumnName ="id")},
                                inverseJoinColumns={@JoinColumn(name ="user_id", referencedColumnName ="id")})
private User user;

@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "vehicle_id")
private Vehicle vehicle;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date startDate;

@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd/MM/yyyy")
private Date finishDate;

public Booking() {

//getter and setter and other code
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: I think you should take the id from Booking? booking.getId()

Comment: In requestParam i search for the vehicle id, not booking id ;)

Comment: You say"Booking of a specific car" so why don't you add a mapping of the Vehicle to your Booking entity then you can get the vehicle id with a getter

Comment: `vehicleID` should then be part of your `Booking` object because you want to validate the booking right? But the booking is not valid without a `vehicleId`.

Comment: Booking domain class has a vehicle object but a vehicleId is assigned to a  booking when the input is correct, not when the validation encounters errors. If i try to fetch the vehicleId from the new booking it is null!

Comment: There is no way to do something similar to that i asked at the begining?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply map the vehicle id as `booking.vehicle.id` in your form? Provided `Vehicle` has a no-arg constructor (which it probably does, being an entity), the `Booking` should come back in the `POST` request handler with an instantiated `Vehicle`, along with its `id` property set. You should then be able to access `booking.vehicle.id` from wihtin the validator.

You can use an `input[type=hidden]` for the `booking.vehicle.id` field. In your `GET` request for the view with the form, simply inject the vehicle id as a `@PathVariable` and copy it to your model, so that you could reference the value inside the form.